# Fabricjs : Export Custom Attributes Assigned To Canvas Objects While Exporting Canvas To JSON

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I'm looking for a code that allows custom properties assigned to the canvas objects to be exported with canvas JSON.

I was trying to save custom attribute to canvas objects. Exporting canvas to JSON, storing it to database and retrieving it back to render it again.

So I needed custom properties to be saved into database to for logic building on frontend.

I was trying to save custom attribute to canvas objects. Exporting canvas to JSON, storing it to database and retrieving it back to render it again.

So I needed custom properties to be saved into database to for logic building on frontend.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved like below.

```
const originalFabricObject = fabric.Object.prototype.toObject;
const canvasAdditionalAttributes = ['customAttribute1','customAttribute2','customAttribute3',...etc];
fabric.Object.prototype.toObject = function (additionalProperties) {
    return originalFabricObject.call(this, canvasAdditionalAttributes.concat(additionalProperties));
}.concat(additionalProperties));
}
```

For Images, It can be achieved like below if you face any errors

```
fabric.Image.prototype.toObject = (function (toObject) {
    return function () {
        return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
            customAttribute1 : this.customAttribute1,
            customAttribute2 : this.customAttribute2,
            customAttribute3 : this.customAttribute3,
            ...etc
        });
    };
})(fabric.Image.prototype.toObject);
```